# couchbase n1qlQuery Delete with sub-query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have one bucket contain 2 types of objects:
first:

```
{
  "id": "123"
  "objectNamespace": "a",
  "value": "value1"
}
```

second:

```
{
  "id": "234",
  "objectNamespace": "b",
  "value": "value2",
  "association": ["123"]
}
```

now I want to delete the document from type `a` only if does NOT have any associations from type `b`:

I try this:

```
 DELETE FROM `bukcet_name` 
  WHERE objectNamespace = 'a' 
   AND id = "123" 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
            WHERE ANY item IN bukcet_name.association 
                  SATISFIES item = "123" END);
```

BUT this always delete the a doc with id 123
How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of mismatches between your data and your query.

(1) You are missing a FROM clause.

(2) You use associations instead of association.

(3) bucket_name.

Here is a possible query.

```
DELETE FROM `bucket_name` 
  WHERE objectNamespace = 'a' 
   AND id = "123" 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM bucket_name b2
            WHERE ANY item IN b2.association
                  SATISFIES item = "123" END);
```

Comment: Did you check you suggestion? this does not even compile?

Comment: Compiles and works for me. I am surprised if you don't understand the etiquette of requesting and receiving help.